# Windows 8 Desktop, HDMI graphics card Audio and video?

Tags: windows-8, hdmi

I have a Windows 8 desktop and I would like to hook it up to my tv via HDMI. However my desktop doesn't have any HDMI output slots. I was wondering if I were to install a graphics card with HDMI output. Whould the graphics card's HDMI output include the audio from my computer Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Some graphics cards can do this, you just have to make sure that you buy the right one. However, have you thought of trying out any simpler methods, such as do you have any form of video out socket that you could buy an HDMI adapter for as this could save you a lot of time.